# ADF Scan Application: Which Library?

Tags: java, python, twain

I need to develop a custom scan application. Up to now I used
old code: tcl/tk and a lot of subprocesses using the command line
interface of the sane project. The app only runs on linux with
an attached Fujitsu ADF scanner.

The code needs to be replaced with a modern solution. We prefer Java or Python
as language.

It would be good if the application could be used on MS-Windows and Linux.

In the past we had problems with hardware support of the sane library. Now we would
like to use TWAIN. There are some open source libraries or applications, but they
all look dead. But AFAIK TWAIN does not work on linux.

Up to now I only used open source stuff (python, linux, django, postgres) but maybe
it is better to buy a commercial library here.

There are some browser plugins, but I think a native GUI would be better.

Does anybody have any recommendations?

Comment: As of twain 2.0, it works on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try EZTwain Pro, http://www.eztwain.com/eztwain4.htm

Has python support, or java, and is actively supported.  I should add I do work for the company that sells it.